# How to disable validation response in Soap web service

Tags: .net, ssl, soap-client

I must call soap Web Service.

To call this web service, I must use SSL certificate and use X509Certificate.

So, I have build this code

```
//certificato 509v3
string pathCertificato = @"C:\Users\michele.castriotta\Desktop\Certificati\keystore_healthnetbr.pfx";
X509Certificate2 certificatoLocale = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(pathCertificato), "changeit");
AsymmetricAlgorithm chiavePrivta = certificatoLocale.PrivateKey;
PublicKey chiavePubblica = certificatoLocale.PublicKey;


PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeClient ws_Client = new PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeClient("PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialePort", "https://edottotest.sanita.regione.rsr.rupar.puglia.it/nsisr/PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeService");
ws_Client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate=certificatoLocale;
ws_Client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = certificatoLocale;

EndpointIdentity identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("HEALTHNETBR");
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://edottotest.sanita.regione.rsr.rupar.puglia.it/nsisr/PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeService"), identity);
ws_Client.Endpoint.Address = address;

ws_Client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "HEALTT";
ws_Client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "ceit";

PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeService.attributiAutorizzativi attributi = new PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeService.attributiAutorizzativi();
attributi.identificativoServizio="getElencoPAIDomiciliare";
attributi.identificativoUtente="HEAR";
attributi.ruoloIstituzionale="RI282";

PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeService.getElencoPAIDomiciliare request = new PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeService.getElencoPAIDomiciliare();

elencoPAIDomiciliareRequest criteriRicerca = new elencoPAIDomiciliareRequest();
criteriRicerca.codiceNazionale = "160";
criteriRicerca.distretto = "3";
criteriRicerca.tipologiaAssistenzaAutorizzata = 0;
criteriRicerca.dataInizioRiferimento = "01/12/2000";
criteriRicerca.dataFineRiferimento = "01/07/2015";

request.criteriRicerca = criteriRicerca;


getElencoPAIDomiciliareResponse response = ws_Client.getElencoPAIDomiciliare(attributi, request);
```

But, I have this error:

> Can not Solve KeyInfo for VERIFICATION Signature : KeyInfo ' SecurityKeyIdentifier \ r \ n ( \ r \ n IsReadOnly = False , \ r \ n Count = 1 , r \ \ n clause [ 0 ] = X509IssuerSerialKeyIdentifierClause ( Issuer = ' CN = testedoca , C = US ' , standard = ' 1342448880 ' ) \ r \ n ) \ r \ n ' , AVAILABLE token ' SecurityTokenResolver \ r \ n ( \ r \ n TokenCount = 1 , \ r \ n TokenEntry [ 0 ] = ( AllowedReferenceStyle = External, token = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken , parameters = System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters : \ r \ nInclusionMode : Never \ r \ nReferenceStyle : Internal \ r \ nRequireDerivedKeys : False \ r \ nX509ReferenceStyle : any ) \ r \ n ) \ r \ n ' .

Now, my question is:
Is possible to disable validation response??

Answer (score 0):

You can check certificate OU installed your system as Certificate Authority.
Details are [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5f3c4f09-2ab1-455e-aac6-dc7e2775538a/how-to-diagnose-exception-cannot-resolve-keyinfo-for-verifying-signature?forum=wcf).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to disable validation using .net httpclient but 
if you are comfortable with java, you could achieve this using either of the following two options :

1. [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/)
2. [HttpsURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html)

It's worth a shot because they are very easy to use and even a naive java developer can use it to call any webservice.